# In Kotlin, why is my local boolean variable not being set from an .addOnSuccessListener call?

Tags: kotlin

I can clearly see my logs showing up, but the isCreated variable is always true.The below function never returns false, only true. Is there a way I can get this function to edit the isCreated boolean inside the .addOnSuccessListener?

```
fun isDocumentCreated() : Boolean{
val fbUser = Firebase.auth.currentUser

            if (fbUser == null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "User is not logged in..")
                return false
            }
val db = Firebase.firestore
val docRef = db.collection("users").document(fbUser.uid)

var isCreated = true
            docRef.get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                    if (document.exists()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: ${document.data}")
                        isCreated = false
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
                        isCreated = false
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", exception)
                }
            return isCreated
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`docRef.get()` is asynchronous operation, `isDocumentCreated()` executed and returns `true` before `addOnSuccessListener` is triggered. you need to use `await()` to execute it synchronously:

```
docRef.get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                    if (document.exists()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: ${document.data}")
                        isCreated = false
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
                        isCreated = false
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", exception)
                }.await()
```

`await()` is and extension function and you need to add dependency to import it:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.3.7"
```